# @wordpress/create-block image url in css

Tags: images, css, urls, block-editor, custom-background

how to include image URL to css "style.css" in custom block?

Both these not work:

```
background-image: url("images/imagename.png");
background-image: url("./images/imagename.png");
```

Image was compiled with hash like **imagename.asdasdasd.png** but the path on frontend is bad (not aiming to plugin).

**Gutenberg editor link (in administration - working):**

```
http://webname.test/app/plugins/wwb-key-properties/build/images/line.d71a3edf.png
```

**Frontend link (not working):**

```
images/line.d71a3edf.png
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default webpack configuration with create-block, and your block.json file in the src folder has `"style": "file:./style-index.css";` you should be able to place the image file inside the same src folder.

For example, you would edit src/style.scss and refer to the image as `background: url('nameofmyimage.jpg') repeat;` inside that scss file and place nameofmyimage.jpg in the src folder.

When you run `npm run build` the default build script provided in create-block and written in webpack, renames the style.scss folder in the /src folder to style-index.css in the build folder and copies the images in the src/ to build/images

so `background: url('nameofmyimage.jpg') repeat;` inside /src/style.scss becomes

`background: url(images/nameofmyfile.jpg) repeat;` inside /build/style-index.css .